# How to restrict getting password using the val() for password fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, input, passwords

I have a form with some `input` fields. For input type `password`, the characters are hidden while typing, but on getting `val()` using input id, credentials can be easily seen by anyone which may cause security problems.

For example, in the below sample, I am printing the password input value in a p tag during the form submit

https://jsfiddle.net/tfo7xu9p/45/

```js
 function myFunction() {
        var passwordval = $("#password1").val();
        document.getElementById("pvalue").textContent = passwordval;
    }
```

```css
form { padding: 20px; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
li { padding: 10px; }
input[type=submit] { float: right; margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="passwordForm"  onsubmit="myFunction(); return false;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="password1">Password 1:</label>
                <input type="password" required id="password1" />
                <p class="error"></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="pvalue">Password Value:</label>
                <p id="pvalue"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Can anyone suggest a way to prevent this type of value taken for password type input alone?**

Regards,

Keerthana.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the password field is to prevent people from looking over the user's shoulder and reading the password.

It isn't designed to stop the user themselves from reading the password they typed.

It isn't designed to stop the website the password field is on from reading the password.

Reading the value with JavaScript can only be done by the above two entities (unless you have an XSS security hole, in which case you need to deal with that).

If you don't want the password to be displayed as plain text that is visible to anyone look looking at the screen, then don't write JavaScript that does that explicitly.